# Click submit and change font color and background color from header in Servlets

Tags: html, servlets

I'm starting a web programming course and I've some trouble changing the font color and font background in my header, Maybe it's very simple but I don't really understand how it works, here is my code, Thanks in advance for your help.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
    out.println("<html>"+
                "<body>"+
                "<h1 align=center>HF\'s Chapter1 Servlet</h1>"+
                "<p>"+ today + "</p</br>"
                                +"<form>"
+"<select>"
+"<option value=\"cyan\">azul cyan</option>"
+"<option value=\"white\">blanco</option>"
+"</select>"
+"<select>"
+"<option value=\"#ff0000\">rojo</option>"
+"<option value=\"black\">negro</option>"
+"</select>"
+"<input type=\"submit\" name=\"btn1 value=\"Enviar Datos/>"
+"</form>"+ "</body>" +"</html>");
}
```

Comment: By the looks of it, you're trying to make a drop down menu in the user interface that will change your heading tag. The simple way to achieve that will be to use javascript. Google something like 'javascript change colour on select field change' and you should get some ideas.

Comment: Thanks for answering @Rusty that's what I want to do! The only problem it's that I'm using netbeans, servlets, jsp, etc. But I will check it out, thanks.

Comment: @Rusty: It's a 20 year old coursework assignment. Any resistance is futile.